# Spivak's Calculus prologue pg 10

Tags: calculus, logic, axioms

After introducing the properties of numbers, Spivak states:

"Note, in particular, that $a>0$ if and only if $a$ is in $P$"

I'm not exactly sure how to prove this. The relevant properties are:

"(P10) (Trichotomy law) For every number $a$, one and only one of the following holds:
(i) $a = 0$
(ii) $a$ is in the collection $P$
(iii) $-a$ is in the collection $P$"

and the definition:

"$a>b$ if $a-b$ is in $P$"

Using a previously introduced property and the definition:

$a$ is in $P \implies a>0$

But how do I show:

$a>0 \implies a$ is in $P$?

Comment: we don't all have the book in front of us.  What is P? and how was it defined.  It sounds like $a > 0$ if and only if $a \in P$  sounds like a definition? Are is there something like you can add something to it to get zero?  Or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of $a \gt 0$ tells you that $a-0 \in P$, and $a-0=a$ so $a-0 \in P \Rightarrow a \in P$.

Comment: If A then B, does not imply if B then A?

Comment: @user1390010 Definitions are if and only if statements, always.

Comment: That's a good question, but in the context of a definition, @PedroTamaroff is correct.

Comment: OK thanks, just one more clarification: does "A if B" always mean "A if and only if B" or only in the context of a definition? (since it is not in the usual "if B then A" structure)

Comment: It really depends on context, but you can pretty much count on that being the case in the context of a definition (because otherwise the language isn't actually defining the concept).

Comment: @user1390010: In general, “A if B” means that B implies A. It is only in definitions that an implication (“if A then B”, “B if A”) that we interpret these implications as really being biconditionals (“if and only if”). Some people use “iff” (which I dislike). Personally, I like to use the explicit “if and only if” when stating definitions.